# Save to a XML document using php problem

Tags: php, xml, dom

Hey all. I'm trying to save A XML file using php. here is my code, the connection to the DB is okay and all, i can use **$dom->saveXML()** but the save function isn't saving nothing.
please help.

```
<?
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM Listing_Arnona WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 



// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("Price",$row['Price']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("PriceS", $row['Price']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['street_name']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("NumRooms", $row['Room_Num']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("PROMO", $row['PROMO']);
} 

$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$test1 = $dom->saveXML(); // put string in test1
$dom->save('test1.xml'); // save as file

?>
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions to `test1.xml`? Are you able to successfully output `$test1` to the browser?

Comment: What does `$dom->save('test1.xml')` return? If it returns `false`, it can't write the file (and most probably that is a permissions issue).

Comment: `isn't saving nothing`? Ah, gotta love them double negatives. What is it saving?

Comment: @Tim $test1 in browser is alright, i didn't check what it returns, i have full root access

Comment: having full root access doesn't mean that script can write to that particular directory. Can you check if it's indeed able to write to that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as everyone pointed out was the writing permissions. i opend a new folder name 'xml' with chmod 777 and changed the code to:

```
$dom->save('xml/test1.xml');
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Excuse me for being blunt, but *you didn't check the return value of the function before posting*? Priceless... http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php